# Protractor/Typescript : uncaught InvalidElementStateError

Tags: protractor

I am writing my first protractor test in Typescript..Here is PageObjectModel class

```
    HomePagePOM.ts


    export module HomePage{
    export class HomePagePom {
    helloTextInput = element(by.model("yourName"));
    helloTextDisplay = element(by.css("ng-binding"));

    launchPage(url: string): void {
        browser.get(url);
        console.log("success");
        browser.waitForAngular();
    }

    typeHello(text: string): void {
        this.helloTextInput.getWebElement().click();
        this.helloTextInput.getWebElement().sendKeys(text);
    }

    getHelloText() : string {
        return this.helloTextDisplay.getWebElement().valueOf();
    }
    }
}


and my spec class HomePageSpec.ts



      import id = require("chai");
      import hpp = require("./HomePagePOM");
      import HomePage = hpp.HomePage;
      var expect = id.expect;
      var assert = id.assert;
      var should = id.should;
      describe("Launch the home page", () => {
          var homePagePom = new HomePage.HomePagePom();
      it("Launch should be successful", () => {
        homePagePom.launchPage("https://www.angularjs.org");
        assert.equal("test", "test", "test is success");

      });

      it("Type Hello Text successfully", () => {
        homePagePom.typeHello("Arun");
        //assert.equal("test", "test", "test is success");
      });

       it("Type Hello Text successfully", () => {
        assert.equal(homePagePom.getHelloText(), "Hello Arun!", " Hello text    typed and retrieved successfully");
       });
     });
```

when I run the test, I get this error as below
   C:\VisualStudio2013\SampleAutomationPOC\SampleAutomationPOC>protractor    conf.js
   [23:02:59] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at     http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
    [23:02:59] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
    [mochawesome] Generating report files...

```
   Launch the home page
 success
   1) Launch should be successful
   2) Type Hello Text successfully
   3) Type Hello Text successfully


  0 passing (4s)
 3 failing
```

1) Launch the home page Launch should be successful:

```
     Uncaught InvalidElementStateError: invalid element state: Failed to execute 'replace' on 'Location': '' is not a valid URL.
  (Session info: chrome=51.0.2704.103)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.21.371459 (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any
 stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 6 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.52.0', revision: '4c2593c', time: '2016-02-11 19:06:42'
System info: host: 'ION3076W7LT-3', ip: '10.210.94.178', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_40'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.21.371459 (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1
cdabed0983e7c4), userDataDir=C:\Users\ion3076\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir10008_16863}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasT
ouchScreen=false, version=51.0.2704.103, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webSt
orageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: 70409fcf7ae2dfd5a1058292d0c30684
```

I have 2 problem
1. obviously the error
2. when the script executes the angularjs.org website doesn't load all the components completely. Meaning some of the components are blank and the loading looks completed. (the object i am interacting is not shown on the page). So while the script is running i tried to hit the refresh button quickly twice and then the page loaded completely. Manually launching everything looks fine.. Not sure what is causing the issue.

The object I am interacting is unique as far as i know..

Any clues to help me out? `enter code here`

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind ..I figured out the answer. For prep reasons i thought of launching the blank browser, I added a line of code browser.get('') in the conf.js under onPrepare() function section. That is causing the issue as ' ' invalid url. I removed it and now it goes through smooth.. long day...and missed to catch the obvious.
Thanks.